# aws dynamodb ListTables functions issue

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless

Got following Cloudwatch error

```
> AccessDeniedException: User:
> arn:aws:sts::<account_number>:assumed-role/abc-ap-southeast-1-lambdaRole/dev-xxxx
> is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:ListTables on resource:
> arn:aws:dynamodb:ap-southeast-1:<account_number>:table/*\n    at
> Request.extractError
> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
```

from (referred : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#listTables-property)

[image]

I have already updated IamRoleStatements in serverless to add ListTables in serverless file.
[image]

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the following documentation [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazondynamodb.html), the resource type of your policy need to be asterisk (*) since you need ListTables action,
for example:

```
iamRoleStatements:
- Effect: "Allow"
  Action:
    - dynamodb:ListTables
  Resource: "*"
```

Comment: Can you please help me figure it?
Is it like dynamodb:* you are talking about?

If it is
I don't want to give access to all policies actually

Comment: I added an example, I hope this help you.